# como hacer peticiones ajax en archivo externo desde laravel 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-6

antes que nada muchas gracias por el apoyo, me gustaría pedir ayuda con respecto a peticiones ajax en archivos externos en laravel 6, ya que en mis rutas no funciona con el helper {{ Route('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor') }}

Route::group(['middleware' => 'administrador'], function () {Route::POST('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor', 'ProfesorController@store')->name('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor');
});

:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te **recomiendo** adjuntar el codigo en formato texto y no una imagen. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que usas jQuery puedes utilizar el atributo data en el button

```
<button id="btn_enviar" data-uri="{{ route('tu.ruta') }}">Enviar</button>
```

En tu archivo js usalo de esta forma dentro del on click

```
var url = $(this).data('uri');
```

Esto por que el archivo externo no reconoce los helpers de laravel o bien, puedes incluir el codigo js dentro de blade

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo de verdad me ayudaste